# How to get access token for Facebook Groups API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token

Am quite new to php, facebook graph and stackoverflow so please forgive. Previously, the following in my php script worked to get an access token for a facebook group:
graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={$appId}&client_secret={$appSecret}&grant_type=client_credentials

What should the request be now? (I know my app-scoped user-id if that helps?)

Background: It's a simple server-to-server app to copy photos from a facebook group to a website. Therefore logins don't apply. It's been reviewed and my business verified (that was fun... not!). I've added my app to the group's settings, but can't find the next step. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You need to use a user access token that are admin for the group

Comment: Thanks for answering, I was getting rather afraid of that! Do you have any suggestions for easiest way of getting hold of an admin's user access token? My becoming an admin would be the easiest solution but not always practical. I don't really like the thought of sending reminders to the admin every 60 days and making them do stuff! Do you know of any sample code lying around? As I say, I'm really quite new to this.

Comment: No I have no code doing that

Comment: ok thanks for your time - much appreciated.